# display some part of string on a label

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

Input 1

> string str=" 1    KAUSHAL DUTTA   46  Female      WL      19  WL      2";

Input 2

> string str1= "1   AYAN PAL    38  Male    CNF S5  49 (LB) CNF S5  49 (LB)";

i have two different types of string if user enter string str then the output should be (WL     2)  & if user enter string str1 then the output should be(CNF   S5  49 (LB))

> all the values are dynamic except(WL      (number))   (CNF    (1 alphabet 1
>   or 2 number)  number (LB))

Comment: What is your question? Which programming language you use?

Comment: i am using c# asp.net

Comment: You need to clarify your objective. You can also share a decent example

Comment: @Progressive ok lets take an example i have a string (abcdefghijkl**twm**xyz) everything in this string is dynamic except twm i need to show the output of the values which came after twm

Comment: You can use String.IndexOf() for finding your static string. Then calculate the start index of string after "twm", then you can get the rest by using SubString() method. But you need to sure that input string doesn't contain "twm" except yours.

Comment: @Progressive and if my string is like(abcdefghijkl**twm**xyz**twm**)

then what will happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you frame your input string with some delimiter, then you can easily split the string and you can store it in some array and proceed.

For example, Frame your string as

string str="1@KAUSHAL DUTTA@46@Female@WL 19@WL 2";

After this split the string like

string[] str1 = str.Split('@');

From str1 array, you can take last value str1[5]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

```
//This is the pattern for the first case WL followed by a one or more (+) digits (\d) 
//followed by any number of characters (.*) 
//the parenthesis is to us to be able to group what is inside, for further processing
string pattern1 = @"WL \d+ (.*)";

//Pattern for the second match: CNF followed by a letter (\w) followed by one or two ({1,2}) 
//digits (\d) followed by one or more (+) digits (\d), followed by (LB) "\(LB\)" 
//the backslach is to get the litteral parenthesis
//followed by any number of characters (.*)
//the parenthesis is to us to be able to group what is inside, for further processing
string pattern2 = @"CNF \w\d{1,2} \d+ \(LB\) (.*)";

string result="";

if (Regex.IsMatch(inputString, pattern1))
{
    //Groups[0] is the entire match, Groups[1] is the content of the first parenthesis
    result = Regex.Match(inputString, pattern1).Groups[1].Value;
}
else if (Regex.IsMatch(inputString, pattern2))
{
    //Groups[0] is the entire match, Groups[1] is the content of the first parenthesis
    result = Regex.Match(inputString, pattern2).Groups[1].Value;
}
```